# dbconnect function error

Tags: php

Somewhere within my dbconnect function it is not close in the right spot. I have been over and over it and I still can't find it. 
here is my dbconnect function:

```
    function dbConnect(){
     // Connect to the database:
     $hostname="localhost";
     $database="tblFile";
     $mysql_login="valerie2_shuawna";
     $mysql_password="norris";

     if(!($db=mysql_connect($hostname, $mysql_login, $mysql_password))){
        echo"error on connect";
     }
     else{
        if(!(mysql_select_db($database,$db))){
            echo mysql_error();
            echo "<br />error on database connection. Check your settings.";
        }
        else{
                    echo "I have successfully made a connection to my database and everything
     is working as it should.";
   }
}
```

then here is another part that has the dbconnect():

```
dbConnect();
    $SQL="SELECT fileID FROM tblFile WHERE fileName='".$result."'";
    //echo $SQL;
    $rs=mysql_query($SQL);
    echo mysql_num_rows($rs);
    if(mysql_num_rows($rs)!=0){
        $extension=strrchr($result,'.');
        $result=str_replace($extension,time(),$result);
        $result=$result.$extension;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

I cant not find where it is not seeing where it should be closed at.

Comment: What is the error popping up?

Comment: Nothing happen with the database. I was told that dbconnect function it is not close in the right spot. And I have been over this all day and can't find it.

Comment: I would suggest removing your user/pass in your example code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first part of your code you are missing a bracket

And I will suggest you to use this form of the if statements

```
function dbConnect()
{
     // Connect to the database:
     $hostname="localhost";
     $database="tblFile";
     $mysql_login="valerie2_shuawna";
     $mysql_password="norris";

     if(!($db=mysql_connect($hostname, $mysql_login, $mysql_password))):
        echo"error on connect";
     else:
        if(!(mysql_select_db($database,$db))):
            echo mysql_error();
            echo "<br />error on database connection. Check your settings.";
        else:
            echo "I have successfully made a connection to my database and everything is working as it should.";
        endif; 
   endif; 
}
```

Tell me the result

Comment: Ok now this is what it is doing...0File Uploaded
Select File:then you have your browse button and then the upload button but nothing is still going in at all. User B you  know I been working on this for days. I don't have no clue what I am doing wrong at all.

Comment: I did have the wrong name in the database area so I did correct that.

Comment: but I dont know what else to do.Because it still is not doing what I need it to.

Comment: What you want exactly is uploading a file into folder and assign its name to the DB ?